# socket.ioの非同期通信でバックグラウンドに送られた時落ちる。

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

こんにちは。いつもお世話になっています。
いま現在webソケット通信をするiosアプリを作っています。

環境として
言語はSwiftでライブラリはSIOSocketっていうMITライセンスのを使用して作っています。

その際に幾つか問題が起きていまして。画面遷移の時にそのインスタンスをうまく殺せなくて困っています。(nilを渡しても<-正しいのかわからないですが)
そのせいでバックグラウンドに送られた際に落ちたりしています。ほかにも遷移先で新たなSocketのインスタンスを作って他のとこへ同時にイベントが発生すると死んでしまいます。

ぜひご教示おねがいします。

Comment: とりあえずそのインスタンスが誰かにリテインされてないか調べてみると良いと思います。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113652/how-do-you-find-out-what-is-retaining-an-object-in-instruments

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。
失礼ですが重ねて質問なのですがバックグラウンドに行った時インスタンスを殺す方法はありますか？